# Is OWIN/Self-Hosting required for Web API v2 authorization/authentication

Tags: owin, asp.net-web-api2

I have been trying to learn how to implement authentication and authorization within an ASP.NET Web API v2 project. Does the Web API need to be self-hosted via OWIN before authorization can be implemented or can it still be accomplished when hosting through IIS?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is, but MS have a number of authorisation tutorials that predominantly use IIS with asp.net identity, etc. If you explain in more detail exactly what your concern is, I'm sure more people on this site will be able to give you specific advice. In short: *authentication and authorization (they're not the same thing) **can** be accomplished when hosting through IIS.*

Answer (score 0):

You can host Owin/Web Api in IIS as well.
Remember to install [Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/2.1.0).
Your config file must be called **web.config**.